# How to view a table of tables in Qt?

Tags: qt

I using Qt library. And I need to show a table of tables, and sort data in each sub-table.

For examlple something like this (2x2 table of 3x3 tables)

```
    sub 1   |  sub 2
-------------------------
| i | 0 | 0 | c | 0 | 0 |  s
-------------------------  u
| j | 0 | 0 | d | 0 | 0 |  b
-------------------------  1
| k | 0 | 0 | e | 0 | 0 |
-------------------------------
| a | 0 | 0 | c | 0 | 0 |
-------------------------  s
| b | 0 | 0 | d | 0 | 0 |  u
-------------------------  b
| c | 0 | 0 | e | 0 | 0 |  2
-------------------------
```

Any solutions are welcome.

ps. My idea is to implement a custom model with 2d array of models.

Comment: Is the number of subtables fixed (e.g. always 2x2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest QTableView instances through use of the [QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget) method. The data structure you use to maintain the QAbstractTableModel instances is inconsequential as long as each QTableView is assigned an appropriate model instance.